# Issue Downloading file more than 20MB in MVC .net application from different server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am downloading files from the server in an .net MVC application. The download is stopped after 21.3 MB. I get a server timeout exception. I suspect there is issue with the IIS server. I need to know how do I increase the IIS server limit downloading the file. My files are more than 50 MB.

Comment: If you want help configuring the IIS server then this off topic for StackOverflow -> ServerFault would be more appropriate.  If you're asking about the possibility that your code is wrong, however, then we need to see the code you're using to be able to provide help.

Answer (score 0):

Try Increasing Limit in your webconfig file

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="60000000" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```